# Java Switch Doesn't get the right case

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement

So I would have a code like this

```
switch (in) {
case "Hi":
  out = "Hello"
case "Who are you":
  out = "I am your personal Assistant 'Buddy'"
}
return out;
```

and in another class I would have

```
System.out.println(getAnwser(in));
```

So I would `Hi` and switch would give me: `"I am your personal Assistant 'Buddy' "`

But It should give me `"Hello"`

Any Idea why that happens??

Comment: you forgot to add break statements

Comment: The duplicate link is not _exact_, but the accepted answer correctly explains what you are seeing.  If someone has a better link, then feel free to edit.

Comment: You enter in the first `case` statement but as you forgot the `break` statement, you then enter in the second `case` statement. In the end, `out` contains the second string.

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013682/abstract-class-return/50013853#50013853)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason your code is not working because you forgot to close the case statement with breaks. Hence in your case, the "out" variable is first assigned *Hello* and then it is assigned **I am your personal Assistant 'Buddy' ** since nothing is stopping the compiler from doing so. Hence, you should use break. Edited code:

```
switch(in){
        case "Hi":
            out = "Hello";
            // add a break here to escape the switch statement
            break;
        case "Who are you":
            out = "I am your personal Assistant 'Buddy'";
            // always add a break, always...
            break;

            return out;
          }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. So please *edit* your answer and explain what this does and why it should be used

Comment: your code is missing a closing } (, a default statement) and an explanation